# When reload, page jumps to random section

Tags: javascript, forms, contacts

I am using this tutorial for the contact form of my website :

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-neat-html5-powered-contact-form--net-20426

The form works great, however when the page is first loaded and even when it is reloaded, it automatically jumps to the contact section.

To see what I mean: http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio_original/

And this is what the website should actually do (load to the top of the page or wherever you left off): http://www.averyeliasdesign.com/

I'm assuming it has something to do with the javascript but I can't figure it out. If anyone could help me out that would be wonderful!

Comment: I am assuming your `script.js` is setting focus on the name field on page load.

Comment: What you want is "submit the form and then go to home page"?

Comment: The problem is when you go to website it doesn't take you to the homepage (which is the top of the page), it takes you to the contact section for some reason. You'll see if you go to any section of the website then refresh, it takes you back to the contact page which I don't want! There are no problems with the actual form submission.

Comment: can you comment lines 44 to 46 in your script.js file and try?

Comment: The person below figured it out :) thank you though!

Comment: @sushil those lines only run if 1. Modernizr says the current browser doesn't support the `autofocus` attribute, and 2. The `autofocus` attribute is present. Commenting those lines would only "fix" the issue in older browsers.

Comment: oh I see. I thought the `autofocus` attribute was being set from the js. @Chev's answer is correct.

Comment: My website is also supposed to scroll up/down nicely, but when I added the contact form the smooth-scroll.js stopped working. Do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: Figured it out- it was the ajax file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove this:

[image]

The `autofocus` attribute is giving that field focus and the browser is scrolling the focused field into view.